# Access a class from 2 level outside in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

i just wanna access the public class which is 2 levels outside from the fla file. My folder structure as follows.

- com
- displays
- main.fla

Some fla's are located in displays folder. And i want to access the globalvar.as from fla's which is located in displays folder.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Does this relate to Adobe/Apache Flex?

Comment: The whole idea of global state is [bad practice](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/), and may not be practical with multiple swfs anyway, due to application and security domains. Can you clarify what the real goal is? It might be possible to help you find a better solution using events, exposed properties and methods, and Interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone can help you - you need to get your terminology right.  You want to access a *class* programatically, not an '.as' file (even if the .as file contains the definition of the class). And you want to access it from another class, not from a '.fla' file.

Anyway, what you need to do it import globalvar.as in the class that needs to access it, and (assuming it's a static class, which it should be) just access it like this globalvar.myVarName (where 'globalvar' is the case-sensitive name of the class, and 'myVarName' is the name of the var you want to access).

Using an IDE like [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) (which is an excellent product) makes this sort of thing much easier - if you're interested in AS3 development I would really recommend it.

Comment: The real goal is to develop an e-learning application in as3. And for this there should i need to load swf's in one loader. and i need to pass the variables from swf slides to the main class. so that i need to pass variable/message from swf at the end of the frame..